# wide equation: Any suggestion to solve this problem

Tags: equations, two-column

[image: Wide equation]
Any suggestion to solve this problem... Thanks a lot

Comment: use one of the amsmath package multi-line environments, and don't use math italic for text!! such as `if` or `is immediately...`

Comment: Rewrite or rephrase, nothing else will work in a two column setting

Comment: ...or `Otherwise`.

Answer (score 9):

Use a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\partial_{ab}(i,j)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \parbox[t]{.5\displaywidth}{
    \raggedright
    if $(j,i,a)$ is immediately followed
    by the same job that follows $(j,i,b)$}
\\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Is there an advantage to using `0.5\displaywidth` instead of, say, `0.5\columnwidth`? Both `\displaywidth` and `\columnwidth` happen to be equal to 229.5pt for this MWE.

Comment: @Mico `\displaywidth` can be different from `\columnwidth`.